# @font-face - how to make it work on all browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

> The @font-face rule is supported in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox,
>   Opera, Chrome, and Safari.
>
> However, Internet Explorer 9 only supports .eot type fonts, while
>   Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support .ttf and .otf type fonts.
>
> Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the
>   @font-face rule.

This text is from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp). So in order to have working @font-face for IE9 I should just specify EOT font file:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('Sansation_Light.ttf'),
     url('Sansation_Light.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```

Particularly I am using Myriad Pro, and I have OTF fonts. How I can convert them into EOT type?

And regarding to IE7 and IE8 what trick/hack should be used to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Forget everything w3schools tells you. Chance is high, its just plain wrong. See my link in the other comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have the copyright to embed most fonts - anyone can download them, so it's no different to putting the font on your server for someone to download.

My advice would be to use the font squirrel tool found here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to generate the files and the code for you.

Be careful not to share fonts you don't have the rights to do so with.

Comment: Oh, it works for IE9 thanks, does it also work for IE7 and IE8? :) And How I should prevent of sharing fonts? Users can see the address of the link in CSS code and can just download the file.

Comment: @Karine EVERYTHING your client can see on your webpage, (regardless of being code, pictures or fonts) is already downloaded to his computer, so you can't prevent users from "stealing and using your precious font". Thats how the Web works.

Comment: And why Myriad Pro is blacklisted in http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator? How to handle with that font?

Comment: 1. I find jacks answer far more useful. 2. Myriad Pro is not free to use!! Thats why it's blacklisted.

Comment: @Christoph I wonder why should the code generated (which is the same with jack's answer) should fix the problem with IE7 and 8 if it is clearly stated: Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the '@font-face' rule.

Comment: IE is the first browser which supports font face. If you embed .eot fonts it will work form IE4 and up.

Comment: @karine I strongly recommend you this link: [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com). Please read and never trust w3schools again!

Answer (score 9):

I think this is almost fully cross-browser

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Name';
    src: url('location.eot');
    src: url('location.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('location.woff') format('woff'),
         url('location.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('location.svg#Name') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Location is the path on your server, and Name is the font's name

Comment: Which one from this is for IE7 and IE8??

Comment: I would also add - http://onlinefontconverter.com/myfonts.php  link for font conversion.

Comment: If we're going for "work on all browsers" then don't bother with the weight and style properties. IE < 9 doesn't support them and resorts to faux-bold etc. Better to define all your weights etc as differently named fonts.

Comment: `url('location.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')` is really important for IE8 or lower. IE's emulator wont pick up any problems until on real browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome Font';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Awesome Font'),
       url('/fonts/awesome.woff2') format('woff2'), 
       url('/fonts/awesome.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/awesome.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/awesome.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

The local() directive allows you to reference, load, and use locally installed fonts.

The url() directive allows you to load external fonts, and are allowed to contain an optional format() hint

Answer (score 0):

Jacktheripper already posted a good font-face,

i recommend you the following good articles on that topic:

[Article from Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

[Article from fontspring](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax)

Personally, i use [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)  and am very satisfied with it. You have no troubles converting the fonts, embedding the right code, and worrying about copyright issues with a good variety of available fonts.

Comment: How you use Google web fonts? This was something new to me.

Comment: Just click the link and follow the instructions, it's really easy peasy. Try it, and if you have any further questions feel free to ask me;)