# ASP.NET MVC3 can't access font (static content)

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-3, webfonts

I'm having a weird problem with MVC3 I think.
My css file includes a @font-face for IE like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGardeNormal;
    src: url('fontname.eot');
}
```

It works fine locally (on my machine), but when I publish to the server (Azure) I'm getting this error: (like it's trying to access the font file like an action in a controller)
Error (System.Web.HttpException): The controller for path '/Content/fontname.eot' was not found or does not implement IController.

And of course the font doesn't load.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set "Build Action" to "Content" for each font file, otherwise they will not be deployed.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could verify if a reference, content or data file is part of your deployment or not. Most of the common are described here:

**First** you can check the property of the reference, or static content to see if "Copy Local is set to "True".

**Second**, you can unzip the CSPKG file (rename it to zip if needed) and then unzip the CSSX file which is inside CSPKG. After unzipping the CSSX file you can see what is available there because this is what will be available to your application after deployment.

**Third**, if you have access to your Azure VM over RDP, you can just login using your RD credentials and look for drive E: and folder Approot\ folder for all your references and static content.

Answer (score 0):

When I catch those exceptions using ELMAH, in my experience, 100% of the time it is because my deployment didn't deploy the font file.   You should double check the file exists on the server.

Comment: I catch them with ELMAH too. I will check, though why wouldn't it deploy the font files, but everything else does deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this week, deploying an MVC app with downloadable fonts to a server running IIS.

For IIS to return the correct content it uses a look up table called MimeTypes.
Basically a file extension look up. You will have to add the .eot file extension to the Mimetypes in IIS or in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
     <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
   </staticContent>    
</system.webServer>
```

The second part which wasn't apparent to me at first was to add a httpHandler in your project to serve the font files on a http request.

```
<system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
     <add verb="*" path="*.eot" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
   </httpHandlers>    
</system.web>
```

Not all browsers will support the eot fonts. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654166/font-face-how-to-make-it-work-on-all-browsers)