# @fontface not working on ie8

Tags: css, font-face

I am using the following `@fontface` integration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'my_Font';
    src: url('fonts/my-font.eot');
    src: url('fonts/my-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/my-font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/my-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/my-font.svg#MyFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and it isn't working in IE8, why is this? Shouldn't it work? I have checked and double checked if the font is in that directory, and it is there.

I'm testing within a VirtualBox

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654166/font-face-how-to-make-it-work-on-all-browsers

Comment: Can you provide an example of this not working?

Comment: @97ldave do you really need any more examples than the code above? The issue is simple as showed on the question description. I'd show you more if JsFiddle let me embed custom fonts temporarily.

Comment: @GEspinha the reason I ask is because there doesn't look anything wrong with your CSS.